# How to display data on the page without putting code to display data in class definition

Tags: php, sql, mysql, oop, class

I have function with simple sql query to list tickets on the page:

```
class DBQuery
{
  function displayTicketsList(){
    $this->dbConnection();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tickets";
    $this->result = mysql_query($query);
    $this->dbClose();
  }
.
.
.
}
```

How to display data on the page without putting code to display in class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't that clear, but I think you mean something like this:

```
class DBQuery
{
  function displayTicketsList(){
    $this->dbConnection();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tickets";
    $this->result = mysql_query($query);
    $this->dbClose();

    return $this->result;

  }
.
.
.
}
```

and then in your "view", or whatever:

```
$myClass=new DBQuery;
$foo=$myClass->displayTicketsList();

print_r($foo);
```

Comment: I highly doubt `print_r()` is going to produce the desired result for a user-facing web page. At a minimum DBQuery should return the query results in a format that the view can process, whether that's a simple array of associative row arrays or a new model class that encapsulates that data and provides meaningful ways to access the values.